# Setup nginx in docker. Want to send request from docker backend container to internet

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a backend container in internal docker network, which is not accessible to the internet.

Through nginx proxy i want to send request (webhook to slack) from backend server to outside world. Is it possible at all?

I have this config for nginx:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

server_name localhost;

client_max_body_size 100M;
charset utf-8;

... # setup for server containers
}

server{
  listen 443;
  server_name hooks.slack.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            https://hooks.slack.com/;
    proxy_redirect        off;
    proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
    #proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; #Gets CSS working
    #proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Comment: For this to work you need to route the DNS record of hooks.slack.com to your proxy or route all outgoing requests through it

Comment: What's the advantage of putting a proxy in between? Why don't you just connect directly to `hooks.slack.com`?

Comment: @slauth this usage would be for a proxy not a reverse proxy I presume

Comment: @Noam right. But still I don't see the advantage :)

Comment: @slauth neither do I but that's what he's asked. There is a point to understand the use case to give better help so I think I understand the reasoning for you're question 